# tell maven to get JAR dependency from given URL

Tags: maven, dependencies

Unfortunately, my project has an external dependency that was never published to any Maven repository. The only way I can get it is by direct download from github (they pushed the binary to github).

One (bad) way is to download the jar manually and commit/push it to my code repository (git). It wouldn't help me to manually deploy this artifact in my local binary repository because I share this project with external contributors that cannot access my private binary repo.

I wonder if maven has a better way to handle this? (Given that I can't upload the artifact to my repo or public repo).

I know that **npm** allows getting some dependencies from URL. Does maven support it as well?

Comment: Why is it a bad way to download the jar and commit it to your repo? It has some advantages: The artifact gets Maven coordinates, it is always available and doesn't "magically" change. You probably do not need to this very often. Another way would be to check out the git repository and build and deploy the artifact yourself.

Comment: We do what @JFMeier mentioned all the time for artifacts like these, for the reasons he mentioned. We created a separate repo in Nexus to host the third party artifacts that aren't in public Maven repositories we can proxy.

Comment: @JfMeier - I wasn't clear enough. I meant that it's a bad idea to commit the jar into the source repository (git). Of course it's a good idea to deploy it to a local private Maven repository (Nexus/Artifactory) but in this case - It wouldn't help me as I'm sharing this project with external contributors.  I edited my post so it would be more clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no nice way to handle this. You could

- Write a script that downloads the jar and installs it in your local Maven repository. This script could be shared through your code repository.
- Include downloading and installing the artifact into the Maven build process (by writing a Maven plugin or using the antrun plugin)
- Set up a nexus in the cloud that everyone in your team can access.